# Php api help to show the true or false

Tags: php, rest

https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/blob/master/api.php

I above one giving the results via api. See the example below.
http://computerhelpline.us/ip/api.php/wp_posts?filter=ID,eq,21

Instead of showing the results I want to make it as true or false if found 1, not found 0. I don't want to show all the details. Thanks

Example link:http://computerhelpline.us/ip/api.php/wp_posts?filter=ID,eq,21

Can some one make that change I am not good in php thanks.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you're asking for help with changing the github-hosted code, your URL parameters or your own code that you didn't show us. For me, this is unclear, but maybe someone else can make more sense of it.

Comment: I have not made any changes in the script. I have a database I have connected that database to the php script to work with api.  In the below link http://computerhelpline.us/ip/api.php/wp_posts?filter=ID,eq,21 ,   ID is the column name and eq means equals to 21. It will show the entire row of the ID 21. Here I don't want to show anything just want to show found or not found. Like 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

just check number of rows greater than 0 if it's zero return true else return false.
**To check No. of rows:**

```
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I know that code I am not sure where I have to insert that code in that php script. I tried hell lot of trails but no success.